Asynchronous Python SNMP Script to Retrieve VLAN Information from Cisco Routers
I'm developing a Python script using pysnmp with asyncio to collect VLAN information from Cisco routers and switches. So far, I have successfully performed SNMP walk operations on several devices. However, I am struggling to find a "default" or universal MIB that works reliably across different Cisco models for retrieving VLAN information.
I have been using the following MIBs to query VLAN data:
CISCO-VLAN-BRIDGING-MIB (1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.214)
CISCO-VLAN-GROUP-MIB (1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.46)
CISCO-VLAN-IFTABLE-RELATIONSHIP-MIB (1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.68)
CISCO-VLAN-MEMBERSHIP-MIB (1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.68)
CISCO-VLAN-TRANSLATION-MIB (1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.150)

Despite using these MIBs, some devices still do not return any VLAN information. Here's a version of my script:
import asyncio
from pysnmp.hlapi.v1arch.asyncio import *

async def run():
snmpDispatcher = SnmpDispatcher()

iterator = await getCmd(
    snmpDispatcher,
    CommunityData("Redacted", mpModel=0),
    await UdpTransportTarget.create(("Redacted", 161)),
    ("1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.68", None),
)

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = iterator

if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
elif errorStatus:
    print(
        "{} at {}".format(
            errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
            errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or "?",
        )
    )
else:
    for varBind in varBinds:
        print(" = ".join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))

snmpDispatcher.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()

asyncio.run(run())

Are there any best practices or general approaches for querying VLAN information from Cisco devices using SNMP? For example, should I try to query multiple MIBs sequentially as a fallback strategy to maximize the chances of success? Once I get the information I should parse it so that I can then store it in a database, so I am looking for a method with a high probability of success.

This is just a programmer site, where you might meet a Cisco expert with very low probability.

I fear you may have stumbled into Cisco's world of "community string indexing." I gave an answer about it some years ago. Here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71354279/6284025, see if that helps you with your problem.
